# Check all the lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a bit stuck, I need a way to make sure all the lines contain "new" in the status or otherwise return false,

```
var found = data.Lines.find(function(line) {
  if (line.status.some(({
      status
    }) => status !== "new")) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

See example http://jsfiddle.net/sucL9rnm/10/

Data

```
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "Lines": [{
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gotchu man. Here's a simple solution with a for-loop:

---

```
function isFound() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.Lines.length; i++)
    if (data.Lines[i].status[0].status !== 'new')
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sucL9rnm/24

---

This function will return *`true`* only if all nested elements of data.lines have the "new" status attribute. Give it a try. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution :

```js
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "Lines": [{
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "status": [{
        "status": "new"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
console.log(data.Lines.every(d => d.status[0].status === 'new'));
```

Comment: Some line may not have status property which might break. see example http://jsfiddle.net/sucL9rnm/27/ - so in that case it should return false

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map` and `.filter`:

```
data.Lines.filter(line => {
  return line.status && line.status.map(item => item.status)
  .filter(status => status == 'new')
  .length == 0
})
.length > 0
```

This solution takes into account that `data.Lines` may have a `status` with more than one object in it.

Comment: Some line may not have status property which might break. Should return false

Comment: I'll update my answer accordingly, but that is information that would have been useful to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just an approach using short IF and filter

```
(data.Lines.filter(o=>{
   return o.status[0].status !='new';
}).length)?console.log(false):console.log(true)
```

With status length more than 0:

```
(data.Lines.filter(o=>{
    return o.status.filter(o2=>{
        return  o2.status !='new';
   }).length
}).length)?console.log(false):console.log(true)
```

Here a non-standard approach, the advantage, is not necessary to know exactly how the object is.

```
(data.Lines.length == JSON.stringify(data).match(/new/g).length)?console.log(true):console.log(false);
```

Comment: It need to check everything in status array  rather than `status[0]`